# clang/clang++ not detecting standard header files like iostream.h and stdio.h

Tags: clang, clang++

I ran `clang++ -v testfile.cpp` and found that many standard headers were missing from the directory `C:\LLVM\lib\clang\3.9.0\include`. I downloaded a pre-built binary of clang 3.9.0 for 32 bit windows from [this link](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).

Can someone please help me sort out this mess and explain me why the standard libraries are missing in the pre-build version of clang? I've searched the web for hours to get the answer and solution to this problem but couldn't find one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a standard header file, the standard header file is called `iostream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the standard libraries are missing in the pre-build version of clang?

Your Windows binary download comprises only binary build tools
plus a handful of clang-specific headers because you are supposed
to use clang, on Windows, in lieu of another native compiler that provides your
standard library. Similarly if you install clang on Linux you'll build against
the GCC standard library by default.

Your internet search seemingly failed to lead you to [Installing clang++ to compile and link on Windows](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt1/), which
explains how to integrate clang with the mingw-w64 GCC standard library for 32- and/or 64-bit work
in the manner that clang for Windows expects and supports.